# SpringBoot helloworld MVC application won't load

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm familiar with the old way of using spring with servlet mapping, but I thought I'd try SpringBoot for a new application to get going quicker and use defaults wherever possible.

I can't seem to get the most basic helloworld controller to work.

It seems SpringBoot is not bootstrapping at all.  I put a breakpoint in Application main method and it doesn't break.

Using gradle to build the project, and deploy in tomcat through IntelliJ.

I'm missing something really simple I'm sure.  But what is it?

Here is the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'test'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Servlet initializer:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you deploy it the main won't run. For that just run it as java application.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that would be it.  All the examples are for running a jar with bundled app server.  I really want to just build a war that can be deployed though.  Is SpringBoot able to work as a normal war?

Comment: Actually according to the documentation on "Packaging executable jar and war files" I have the correct config with configurations {
    providedRuntime
} etc.  So I get that the main method won't be used, but I still can't see anything happening.  My root URL gives a 404, and trying to change the log config in application.properties has not affect at all. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging

Comment: Make sure you have a recent version of tomcat. When deploying to tomcat the `ServletInitializer` is used. Also beware that your application is then available not on the root URL but on `/name-of-the-war` on your server.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7 which is Servlet 3.0.  And I have an application context: HTTP Status 404 - /Test/

type Status report

message /Test/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32

Comment: OK I can confirm the ServletIntializer doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.

I started a new application without spring boot.  Just an old fashioned xml based spring application, and with this approach I could see an exception.  It was complaining about compiling in one Java version and running in another.  I was trying to get it working in Java 8.

I have switched back to Java 7 and sure enough, the SpringBoot application works fine.

Thanks PaulINUK for the suggestion.  It's not great that you can't see exceptions if there is an issue when bootstrapping SpringBoot though.

Answer (score 1):

To start with I'd check it works with the embedded configuration (i.e. remove your Tomcat provided dependency from your gradle config) by running the main method.

It's also worth putting on full logging by adding

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG

to your application.properties/yaml

Once you're sure of this, build the war, deploy and post the tomcat server logs. If it's servlet 3+ you should see messages about detected ServletInitializers.

By the way, your @EnableAutoConfiguration is superfluous, as the @SpringBootApplication annotation includes the former:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have tried debug logging but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work because SpringBoot is not boostrapping.  I do agree it's a ServletInitializer issue which seems a bit magical which is never fun when the magic doesn't happen as it's supposed to.  I can see more activity when using the bootRun gradle task so will try to get that working completely before coming back to the ServletInitializer problem.

Comment: I'm working on an app with a similar issue - it just hangs at the servlet initialiser stage on Glassfish with no messages, though working fine on Tomcat. It does seem that some app servers have a tendency to swallow errors at the initialiser stage. 

Glad you got it sorted.